# Problema de FATAL EXCEPTION:main en aplicacion android al iniciar ejecución

Tags: android

```
06-03 13:05:59.780 2512-2512/? I/art: Not late-enabling -Xcheck:jni (already on) 06-03 13:05:59.920
> 2512-2512/com.example.arielra.reproductordeaudio W/System: ClassLoader
> referenced unknown path:
> /data/app/com.example.arielra.reproductordeaudio-1/lib/x86_64 06-03
> 13:06:00.270 2512-2512/com.example.arielra.reproductordeaudio
> D/AndroidRuntime: Shutting down VM 06-03 13:06:00.270
> 2512-2512/com.example.arielra.reproductordeaudio E/AndroidRuntime:
> FATAL EXCEPTION: main
>                                                                                       Process: com.example.arielra.reproductordeaudio, PID: 2512
>                                                                                       java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity
> ComponentInfo{com.example.arielra.reproductordeaudio/com.example.arielra.reproductordeaudio.MainActivity}:
> java.lang.SecurityException: Permission Denial: reading
> com.android.providers.media.MediaProvider uri
> content://media/external/audio/media from pid=2512, uid=10047 requires
> android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE, or grantUriPermission()
>                                                                                           at
> android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2416)
>                                                                                           at
> android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2476)
>                                                                                           at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(ActivityThread.java)
>                                                                                           at
> android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1344)
>                                                                                           at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
>                                                                                           at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
>                                                                                           at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417)
>                                                                                           at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
>                                                                                           at
> com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726)
>                                                                                           at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
>                                                                                        Caused by: java.lang.SecurityException: Permission Denial: reading
> com.android.providers.media.MediaProvider uri
> content://media/external/audio/media from pid=2512, uid=10047 requires
> android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE, or grantUriPermission()
>                                                                                           at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:1599)
>                                                                                           at
> android.database.DatabaseUtils.readExceptionFromParcel(DatabaseUtils.java:183)
>                                                                                           at
> android.database.DatabaseUtils.readExceptionFromParcel(DatabaseUtils.java:135)
>                                                                                           at
> android.content.ContentProviderProxy.query(ContentProviderNative.java:421)
>                                                                                           at android.content.ContentResolver.query(ContentResolver.java:491)
>                                                                                           at android.content.ContentResolver.query(ContentResolver.java:434)
>                                                                                           at
> com.example.arielra.reproductordeaudio.MainActivity.audioCursor(MainActivity.java:69)
>                                                                                           at
> com.example.arielra.reproductordeaudio.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:47)
>                                                                                           at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6237)
>                                                                                           at
> android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1107)
>                                                                                           at
> android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2369)
>                                                                                           at
> android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2476) 
>                                                                                           at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(ActivityThread.java) 
>                                                                                           at
> android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1344) 
>                                                                                           at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
>                                                                                           at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148) 
>                                                                                           at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417) 
>                                                                                           at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
>                                                                                           at
> com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726) 
>                                                                                           at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)  06-03
> 13:06:04.180 2512-2512/? I/Process: Sending signal. PID: 2512 SIG: 9
```

Adjunto imagen con el error obtenido en el emulador:

[image: Error]

Comment: Podrias agregar el codigo que falla en tu aplicación y la configuración relacionada con el error. Aunque parece que problema es de permisos **Permission Denial: reading**

Comment: @BRYANORELLANA, exactamente lo que menciona jasilva.  "requires android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE, or grantUriPermission()"

Answer (score 2):

No tienes permisos de lectura para el almacenamiento externo!. Agrega dentro de tu `AndroidManifest.xml` el permiso:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

> **Permiso [READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/Manifest.permission.html#READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE)** : Permite a la aplicación leer de el
>   "almacenamiento externo". (No requerido en API 19).

Answer (score 1):

Tienes la respuesta en el StackTrace:

> Permission Denial: reading com.android.providers.media.MediaProvider uri content://media/external/audio/media from pid=2512, uid=10047 requires android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE, or grantUriPermission()

Agrega el permiso `android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE` a tu Manifest